# Change product attribute type in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Hope everything is well at all of your end.

I am changing type of product attribute. But I am bit confuse after changing type of attribute, it will assigned to all products the same or not.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It will be assigned to all products, and changes will be reflacted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If I have assigned that attribute to product A, B and D then after changing product attribute type it will be assigned. Am I right? no need to assign again.

Comment: Right, attribute will be assigned but the value may no be set the same as before.